# Kohana3 Auth sessions life

Tags: php, kohana, authentication

On my site, when you log in, I want to keep these sessions alive for 10 hours.

Right now my session ends when i close my browser. How can i extend this?

I have checked auth lifetime in config, and its set to 2 weeks (in seconds) by default, but still it does not keep me in.

Im using Kohana with the Auth module that is included.

Answer (score 0):

PHP sessions by default will expire when the browser window closes.
You'll need to modify `session.cookie_lifetime` in php.ini or use `ini_set('session.cookie_lifetime', 36000)` or [session_set_cookie_params(36000)](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-set-cookie-params.php) to leave the session cookie alive for 10 hours after browser close.